# Azure Functions raises an error with Marklio

Tags: azure-functions

I've just deployed an update for my Azure Functions: there are different functions with timer or servicebus trigger. I noticed in the last couple of days an error/warning related to `Marklio`, a package that I don't use in my project. Here the packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle" Version="3.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" Version="3.0.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob" Version="11.1.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault" Version="3.1.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Xero.Api.SDK.Core" Version="1.1.4" />
```

There error I found on Application Insights is

> System.InvalidOperationException at Marklio.Metadata.MetadataExtensions.g__RecursiveGetFullName|9_0
>
> Marklio.Metadata.MetadataExtensions.g__RecursiveGetFullName|9_0
>
> assembly DotNetTI.BreakingChangeAnalysis, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>
> Unsupported TypeRef (has module as resolution scope)

Here a screenshot of the details.

[image]

```
[
   {
      "severityLevel":"Warning",
      "parsedStack":[
         {
            "assembly":"DotNetTI.BreakingChangeAnalysis, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "method":"Marklio.Metadata.MetadataExtensions.<GetFullName>g__RecursiveGetFullName|9_0",
            "level":0,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"DotNetTI.BreakingChangeAnalysis, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "method":"Marklio.Metadata.MetadataExtensions.<GetFullName>g__RecursiveGetFullName|9_0",
            "level":1,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"DotNetTI.BreakingChangeAnalysis, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "method":"Marklio.Metadata.MetadataExtensions.GetFullName",
            "level":2,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"DotNetTI.BreakingChangeAnalysis, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "method":"Marklio.Metadata.DocIdExtensions.GetDocId",
            "level":3,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"DotNetTI.BreakingChangeAnalysis, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "method":"DotNetTI.BreakingChangeAnalysis.BreakingChangeReportGenerator+<GenerateProblematicApis>d__6.MoveNext",
            "level":4,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor",
            "level":5,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Linq, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
            "method":"System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList",
            "level":6,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"DotNetTI.BreakingChangeAnalysis, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "method":"DotNetTI.BreakingChangeAnalysis.BreakingChangeReportGenerator.ProduceReport",
            "level":7,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"DotNetTI.BreakingChangeAnalysis, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "method":"DotNetTI.BreakingChangeAnalysis.BreakingChangeReportGenerator.ProduceReport",
            "level":8,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ChangeAnalysis.ChangeAnalysisService.LogBreakingChangeReport",
            "level":9,
            "line":140,
            "fileName":"D:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\\BreakingChangeAnalysis\\ChangeAnalysisService.cs"
         },
         {
            "assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ChangeAnalysis.ChangeAnalysisService+<TryLogBreakingChangeReportAsync>d__12.MoveNext",
            "level":10,
            "line":103,
            "fileName":"D:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\\BreakingChangeAnalysis\\ChangeAnalysisService.cs"
         }
      ],
      "outerId":"0",
      "message":"Unsupported TypeRef (has module as resolution scope)",
      "type":"System.InvalidOperationException",
      "id":"65095906"
   }
]
```

I'm not sure if and when my code is using/calling this function and what kind of impact it can be on my function.